# Running local notifications with hourly interval every day for specific amount of time

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, localnotification

How can I make my app to be able to fire local notifications every day with customisable interval but only for allocated amount of time, for example: from 10:00 to 20:00pm?

Now I only implemented repeated notifications with custom interval:

```
    func beginNotifications(_ config: UserConfig) {

    let interval = config.notificationInterval

    let center =  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Content title"
    content.subtitle = "Content body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request)

}
```

By far I only came up with solution - to make two separate methods using Timer, which will start and stop notification function daily, and enable Background Mode for the app.

Comment: There's no easy solution to this but I think your best bet is to use [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) instead of UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger. You will need to create a request for each time that you want the notification to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution came to my mind if scheduling the local push notification N-times (how many times as you want). You just need to make the `identifier` unique of course.

[image]

---

> By far I only came up with solution - to make two separate methods
>   using Timer, which will start and stop notification function daily,
>   and enable Background Mode for the app.

This isn't recommended imo, and if you push this, you might need to deal with Apple review team.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn. "...local push notification N-times..." - yea I was thinking the same.

Comment: Perhaps consider selecting an answer or posting your own answer? :) But sure, you're welcome. Happy coding.